# synaptic do not show packages long description

Tags: linux, debian, repository, synaptic

Since I upgraded my Debian version to Buster I am not able to see the long description of the packages in synaptic wich affect the way I search for them. I thing is maybe a configuration issue but could not figure out how solve the problem. Any idea of how fix it will be helpful.[image]

Comment: Do you mean the window containing the description is missing? Can you make a screenshot to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: I added a screenshot of synaptic with a package selected

Comment: Thank you. It does indeed look buggy. I started synaptic with `sudo LANG=es_AR.utf8 synaptic` to see what happens when I use a different locale and it looks pretty normal [here](https://i.imgur.com/6xs2DK7.png).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, setting the LANG variable gave me a clue how solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the setting `Acquire::Languages {"none";};` in the configuration of apt placed in`/etc/apt/apt.conf` file. Once the line was removed and ran `apt update` the problem was solved.